# How do I make it so that my camera shows the actual objects?

Tags: camera

So I have been doing a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icMn25j2yy0&t=223s) and for some reason when I did the camera rigging part, the screen just goes black. This is when I view what the camera sees. Any tips?

This is my project file:
[Blender File Link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nilfvyafkilqezt/SatisfyingAttempt.blend/file) (MediaFire)

Trying images now:
Out of camera: [image: OutOfCamera]
In camera: [image: InCamera]

Comment: Please don't make the question depend on downloading a file. Edit your question and show images of the interface and settings.

Comment: My wifi is very bad currently and I wasn't able to upload the images for some reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) # 21 "camera is not pointing at the object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your camera is panned, you just need to press <kbd>Numpad0</kbd> to go inside the camera and then press <kbd>Home</kbd>

[image]