# Camera View is grey

Tags: camera

[image]I am relatively new to blender and have had a problem when trying to enter into camera view. When pressing  <kbd>Numapd 0</kbd> it goes to a grey screen with no grid lines.

It renders perfectly fine but I just can't get the camera to show what I have created. Open to suggestions.

The Image is what happens once clicking  <kbd>Numapd 0</kbd>.

Comment: When you press Numbpad 0, what happens if then you press HOME on your keyboard? does that fix the issue? Does this answer your question? [How do I make it so that my camera shows the actual objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191853/how-do-i-make-it-so-that-my-camera-shows-the-actual-objects)

Comment: Yes, that worked thank you so much, life saver :).